# MySQL - Write an UPDATE Query based on SELECT Query on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1064

I am far from being strong in MySQL or database, so I am using a tool called FlySpeed SQL Query. This tool helps me graphically created MySQL queries.
Here is the query I got created with this tool and a lot of reading on the internet.

```
Select
  Employee.Firstname As Prénom,
  Employee.Name As NOM,
  TimeSheet.Filled As Validé,
  TimeSheet.Closed As Clôturé,
  Sum(Imputation.Hours) As `Somme des heures`,
  TimeSheet.Month + 1 As Mois,
  TimeSheet.Year As Année
From
  Employee Inner Join
  TimeSheet On TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id Inner Join
  Imputation On Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id Inner Join
  Project On Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
Where
  TimeSheet.Filled = '1' And
  (TimeSheet.Closed = '0' Or
    TimeSheet.Closed Is Null) And
  Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month) And Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01') And
  Project.Id != '1'
Group By
  Employee.Name, TimeSheet.Month + 1, TimeSheet.Year
Having
  Sum(Imputation.Hours) >= 5 * ((DateDiff(Last_Day(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month), Date_Format(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')) + 1))
Order By
  Année,
  Mois,
  NOM
```

This query returns me exactly the desired result. Keeping the same conditions as the MySQL query above, I want to update the Closed field to "1". I would like to make some things that taste there:

```
-- UPDATE Query
--
UPDATE TimeSheet
SET Closed = '1'
--
-- UPDATE Query
From
Employee Inner Join
TimeSheet On TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id Inner Join
Imputation On Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id Inner Join
Project On Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
--
-- With those conditions
--
Where
TimeSheet.Filled = '1' And
(TimeSheet.Closed = '0' Or
    TimeSheet.Closed Is Null) And
-- Calculating a time range
Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month) And Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01') 
And
Project.Id != '1'
Group By
Employee.Name, TimeSheet.Month + 1, TimeSheet.Year
Having
-- Calculation : >= 5 times the number of days in the period
Sum(Imputation.Hours) >= 5 * ((DateDiff(Last_Day(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month), Date_Format(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')) + 1))
---
-- With those conditions
```

So I need help to turn my SELECT query to an UPDATE query. Feel free to ask me for more information.

Comment: And it's not working? Looks OK at first glance assuming you want to update every record that is returned.

Comment: When I try the query as I thought: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From Employee Inner Join TimeSheet On TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id Inner ' at line 3` (I've uncommented the query posted here before using.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to my problem.

This article helped me a lot: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/831164/MySQL-can-t-specify-target-table-for-update-in-FRO

Here it is:

```
UPDATE TimeSheet 
SET 
    Closed = '1'
WHERE
    TimeSheet.Id IN (SELECT 
            TimeSheet.Id
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                TimeSheet.Id
            FROM
                TimeSheet
            Where
                TimeSheet.Id IN (SELECT 
                        TimeSheet.Id
                    FROM
                        Imputation
                    INNER JOIN TimeSheet ON Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id
                    INNER JOIN Project ON Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
                    INNER JOIN Employee ON TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id
                    Where
                        (TimeSheet.Closed = '0'
                            OR TimeSheet.Closed IS NULL)
                            AND TimeSheet.Filled = '1'
                            AND Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month)
                            AND Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')
                    GROUP BY TimeSheet.Id
                    HAVING TimeSheet.Id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                            TimeSheet.Id
                        FROM
                            TimeSheet
                        INNER JOIN Imputation ON Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id
                        INNER JOIN Project ON Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
                        INNER JOIN Employee ON TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id
                        Where
                            Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month)
                                AND Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')
                                AND Project.Id = '1')
                        AND Sum(Imputation.Hours) >= 5 * (DateDiff(Last_Day(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month), Date_Format(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')) + 1))) VirtualTable01);
```

However the term "solution" is perhaps a bit strong. I would say more it is a workaround. So I'm not sure this request is well optimized and it meets the standards, but at least it has the advantage to give me the desired result.

Same query as above but commented:

```
-- UPDATE Query
--
UPDATE TimeSheet 
SET 
    Closed = '1'
--
-- UPDATE Query
--
-- With those conditions
--
WHERE
    -- First Select
    --
    TimeSheet.Id IN (SELECT 
            TimeSheet.Id
        FROM
            -- Second Select
            --
            (SELECT 
                TimeSheet.Id
            FROM
                TimeSheet
            Where
                -- Third Select
                --
                TimeSheet.Id IN (SELECT 
                        TimeSheet.Id
                    FROM
                        Imputation
                    INNER JOIN TimeSheet ON Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id
                    INNER JOIN Project ON Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
                    INNER JOIN Employee ON TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id
                    Where
                        (TimeSheet.Closed = '0'
                            OR TimeSheet.Closed IS NULL)
                            AND TimeSheet.Filled = '1'
                            AND Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month)
                            AND Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')
                    GROUP BY TimeSheet.Id
                    -- Fourth Select
                    --
                    HAVING TimeSheet.Id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
                            TimeSheet.Id
                        FROM
                            TimeSheet
                        INNER JOIN Imputation ON Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id
                        INNER JOIN Project ON Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
                        INNER JOIN Employee ON TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id
                        Where
                            Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month)
                                AND Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')
                                AND Project.Id = '1')
                    --
                    -- End Fourth Select
                        AND Sum(Imputation.Hours) >= 5 * (DateDiff(Last_Day(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month), Date_Format(Current_Date - INterval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')) + 1))
                -- 
                -- End Third Select
                            ) VirtualTable01)
            -- 
            -- End Second Select
    -- 
    -- End First Select
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `set` operation after the `joins`:

```
UPDATE TimeSheet Inner Join 
   Employee On TimeSheet.Employee_Id = Employee.Id Inner Join
   Imputation On Imputation.TimeSheet_Id = TimeSheet.Id Inner Join
   Project On Imputation.Project_Id = Project.Id
--
-- With those conditions
--
SET TimeSheet.Closed = '1'
Where
    TimeSheet.Filled = '1' And
    (TimeSheet.Closed = '0' Or
    TimeSheet.Closed Is Null) And
    -- Calculating a time range
    Imputation.Day <= Last_Day(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month) And Imputation.Day >= Date_Format(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01') 
    And
    Project.Id != '1'
Group By
    Employee.Name, TimeSheet.Month + 1, TimeSheet.Year
Having
    -- Calculation : >= 5 times the number of days in the period
    Sum(Imputation.Hours) >= 5 * ((DateDiff(Last_Day(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month), Date_Format(Current_Date - Interval 1 Month, '%Y-%m-01')) + 1))
    ---
```

Comment: When I try your query @sgeddes :

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group By Employee.Name, TimeSheet.Month + 1, TimeSheet.Year
Having
    Sum(I' at line 13`

So, your proposal @sgeddes seems more engaged than mine. The query only blocks at the line 13 "Group By". (I've uncommented the query posted here before using.)